# Is there a way to route all jsf calls through one method?

Tags: jsf, design-patterns, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to pass all calls for a bean through a single method? I'd like to stop coding for try/catch blocks for exceptions and displaying them errors to the users for every method I write. I have tried extending my beans through an abstract bean but problem is the methods can be anything and can accept a variety of Classes, such as removeDocument(Document d) or removeAccount(Account a).

Those methods will be on different beans with different names so how can I avoid writing boilerplate code? Thanks.

PS. Granted I can write a filter but I'd like my methods to be closer to where they should be.

Comment: Not as much a JSF question as it is a design question. You could easily fit the Command Pattern anywhere in here

Comment: I am aware that it is a design question but I do have a design where I have a base class which managed beans derive from. Based on the command (string), they take certain actions but certain actions are based on objects such, removeDocument and removeAccount. They are implemented on different beans, short of defining a method that can have a command string and an object as parameters, I can't see how I can implement this. I hate defining an abstract class as an object since I have to cast...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it to me. I think I got a way of solving it without casts.